# Como pegar o valor do index do ngFor

Tags: angular

Poderiam me ajudar em uma duvida, tenho um form com um array onde existe o `FormControl` "id". Existe alguma forma de receber o valor do `index` para preencher este campo?

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of invForm.controls.tool.controls; let i= index" [formGroupName]="i" >
    <td>
        <mat-form-field floatLabel='never'>
            <input matInput type="number" style="text-align: right" formControlName="Id"  value="{{i+1}}"  >
        </mat-form-field>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Fiz este [exemplo no stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/invoice-id).

[Resolvido]

Resolvi o problema com o `trackBy: trackByFn`

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of invForm.controls.tool.controls; let i= index ;trackBy: trackByFn" [formGroupName]="i"  >
```

e no `component`,

```
 trackByFn(index, item) {

     item.value.Id = index+1
    return index; 
  }
```

Deixo aqui também a resolução no [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/invoice-id-resolvido)

Answer (score 20):

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of especialidades; let i = index">
    {{i}} {{item.codigo}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Sintaxe Angular ngFor:
https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-ng-for-syntax

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, porém já tentei com esses métodos e não funcionaram

Comment: Tenta a sim testei aqui deu certo. Posta seu html

Comment: Criar o index e mostrar ele no item da certo, porém quero passar esse index para o `FormControl`. Vou tentar usar o `trackBy: trackByFn`.

Comment: Posta seu FormControl ? para onde vc quer passar!

Comment: Isso não vai funcionar, pois ele deseja aplicar o valor de `i` ao campo do formulário `ID`. O que você está fazendo é exibir na tela, o que não é o que o autor deseja fazer.

Comment: Isso mesmo que o Celso disse, precisava passar o valor do index `i` para o formulário ID. O exemplo está aqui https://stackblitz.com/edit/invoice-id

Comment: vc quer pegar o index do array de elementos no seu .ts ?

Comment: Obrigado pela disposição @LR10, resolvi com o `trackBy: trackByFn` mesmo